# Is there a way to manage layers in MarkupCore?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I built a tool to draw vector shapes, using MarkupsCore.js, on top of a Viewer instance. The issue is that there is no method for handling the layers of MarkupsCore. So, if I load a drawing, it creates the layers from the saved drawing state, but if I create a new drawing, there are no layers. If I need to draw a shape, MarkupsCore creates a layer for me, but some commands delete that layer.

The problem is that the entire handling of layers by MarkupsCore is erratic, sometimes not creating a layer when I expect it to, and sometimes deleting a layer I am certain it created.

Are there methods and tools to handle the creation and managing of layers in a manual way, to make the behavior of the tool more predictable?

Answer (score 0):

The `MarkupsCore` extension object has two properties that might be important for your use case:

- `svgLayersMap` - can be used to get more information about what layers are currently available
- `activeLayer` - controls the editing operations

Comment: I'm aware of them, but the issue is that MarkupsCore still creates and deletes layers when it sees fit. I'd have to set both manually at every step, since I can't trust that a layer will exist at some point in the code. What I need is to make sure layers only get deleted when I ask it to, or something like that.

Comment: Got it. I've double-checked the MarkupsCore implementation, and AFAICT the layers are only ever removed in the following 3 situations: 1. during `markupsCoreExt.show()`, 2. when loading markups into a layer that already exists, 3. when unloading markups in a specific layer.